# WSO2 IS: SCIM API fetch only users from PRIMARY store

Tags: wso2, scim

I have created secondary user store with postgres database and import tables by running script PRODUCT_HOME/dbscripts/postgresql.sql.

In Advance settings for newly created user store I have checked Enable SCIM.

UserStore is working fine, but when i try to fetch users with:

```
curl -k --user admin:adminPass https://server.com:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

I receive only users that are in PRIMARY store. How to receive also users that are from secondary store, or just users from secondary store?

EDIT: It suppose that any newly created user from secondary store can be fetched and it works, only old users that are created before I checked Enable SCIM are not fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a user/group to be retrieved from SCIM APIs, they should have below SCIM specific claims.

```
urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:userName
urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:meta.location
urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:meta.created
urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:meta.lastModified
urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:id
```

When you create a user/group after enabling SCIM in userstore, these claims are automatically created. But since your existing users/groups don't have these claims, SCIM APIs can't retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks. Need to add: Also this claims are automatically created when I add user on the other ways not just with SCIM API it need just to be SCIM enabled in store Advanced settings.